# print value of a variable that is composed for a string into a For Loop

Tags: php

In this loop, I'm trying to take the value of the variable, but to save code I want to use a For Loop to print it concatenating part of the variable with a number genereted into the loop. This is my Try.

```
<?php
$x0 = 0;
$x1 = 1;
$x2 = 2;
$x3 = 3;

for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
echo '$x'.$i;   
}
?>
```

the result that I'm geting is

> $x0$x1$x2$x3$x4

I want it to end up like this:

> 0123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its supposed to be:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo ${"x$i"};
}
```

Sidenote: You'll have to define `$x4` or terminate it to `< 4` so you won't get a undefined index.

Comment: Note: don't use _single quotes_ as  `${'x$i'}`. +1 for answer

Comment: Thank you very much , just what I needed , could you tell me where I can find information about it

Comment: @user3550479 actually its called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). glad this helped

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
    $x0 = 0;
    $x1 = 1;
    $x2 = 2;
    $x3 = 3;

    for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $y='x'.$i;
    if(isset($$y)){
     echo $$y;
     }

    }
```

Comment: It'll generate **Notice: Undefined variable: x4 in**

Comment: Yep good one +1 for you too and try to define why OP should try your way

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
<?php
$x0 = 0;
$x1 = 1;
$x2 = 2;
$x3 = 3;
$string = '';
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
$string .= $i;
}
echo $string;  
?>
```